# C# grammar and switch wildcard

Tags: c#, switch-statement, speech-recognition, wildcard

I would like to add, that whenever it recognizes 'search X' it is going to search for 'X', but i don't know how i have to add that to the grammar, or how to do such a thing with my switch statement.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Choices commands = new Choices();
    commands.Add(new string[] { "hello", "start chrome", "search" });
    GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
    gBuilder.Append(commands);
    gBuilder.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
    Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);

    recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
    recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    recEngine.SpeechRecognized += RecEngine_SpeechRecognized;
}

private void RecEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Result.Text)
    {
        case "hello":
            synthesizer.SpeakAsync("Hello! How are you doing today?");
            break;
        case "start chrome":
            Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
            break;
        case "search":
            SearchChrome("search");
            break;
    }
}

static void SearchChrome(string searchterm)
{
    Process.Start("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + searchterm);
}
```

So i'd like to add to my grammar "Search X", and to my cases "Search X", with it searching for whatever X is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fastest solution is to make an delay to say `X` and wait for user to say `X` and then concatenate it with `Search`. User Says `Search`; he will wait a second and then says `X`. You have activated `Search` Command and then you will search for X. Or you can remove switch and use `IF` statement to check whether the input is begin with Search or not. if it does, you can split the string to get Search Phrase.

Comment: Since it is difficult to know how long is the best to wait and you might be error prone with any value that you choose, why not two use two different keywords for each case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make a more complex grammar. The type of grammar rule you chose is the Choice one. It doesn't suit exactly what you wanna do as you want to capture what follows a keyword. To capture the following you must use the SemanticResultKey rule. It is explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.semanticresultkey?view=netframework-4.7.2

The example matches exactly what you want: it extracts the password from the expression "My password is ....."

Comment: thanks! but how do i get this into my Grammar with the wildcard? When using ` `@"search *"` it says `Search ABC` is `Search *`...

Comment: You must get rid of the switch statement. For the rest of your question, execute the code I posted, you will see how to extract data from an expression.

Comment: Yeah, but how do i get it into my grammar? That's before all this code, in the making of `string input`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake... I was confused by the title of your post. I updated the answer :)

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: would you also happen to know whether there is a way to merge such an GrammarBuilder with the one i already have?

Comment: what do you mean with merge? If my understanding is good, you just have to load you other grammars and it should do the trick